# How to have helper function inherit variables from main function

Tags: r, function, environment, scoping

I would like to set up a function `bar()` which relies on a helper function `foo()`. I am struggling to figure out the cleanest way to setup the variable definitions so I don't have to repeat the definitions in both `foo()` and `bar()`.

This seems like it should work but does not:

```
# helper function
foo <- function() {
 (a + b)/(c - d)
}

# main function
bar <- function(a, b, c, d) {
 z <- foo()
 z * 3
}

bar(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d =  4)
```

This works, but feels repetitive in the function definitions:

```
foo <- function(a, b, c, d) {
  (a + b)/(c - d)
}


# main function
bar <- function(a, b, c, d) {
  z <- foo(a, b, c, d)
  z * 3
}

bar(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4)
```

It works to assign the variables globally first, but not ideal:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
d <- 4 

foo <- function() {
  (a + b)/(c - d)
}

# main function
bar <- function(a, b, c, d) {
  z <- foo()
  z * 3
}

bar(a = a, b = b, c = c, d =  d)
```

Is there a way to force the helper function to recognize the variables defined in the main function?

Comment: The way to do this is to pass the values as parameters, or by defining a closure over the values as shown in markus’ answer. Passing relevant parameters isn’t really “repetitive”, or at least not in a bad way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define `foo` in `bar` then `foo()` will look up for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` in the environment in which it is defined.

```
bar <- function(a, b, c, d) {

  foo <- function() {
    (a + b)/(c - d)
  }

  z <- foo()
  z * 3
}
```

Result

```
bar(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d =  4)
# -9
```

You can read more about it here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping

"... look inside the current function, then where that function was defined, and so on, all the way up to the global environment, and then on to other loaded packages."